# Can Coffeescript access SASS variables?

Tags: coffeescript, sass

I have a palette of colors set as SASS variables. Can Coffeescript access these variables?

SASS
`$red: #f00`

Coffeescript `document.p[0].style.color = $red`

My objective is to rely on the color variables as much as possible as they enforce consistency in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would try to do that:

1. Use a bundler to compile .coffee and .sass in the same environment (I use [hem](https://github.com/maccman/hem), with .stylus files for css and .coffee for javascript)
2. Define a .coffee file who contains color constants
3. Hack a bit the css compilation (LESS/Stylus/SASS) in hem (very readable source code don't worry) to append the variables definitions in the beginning of the files:

   1. varablesDef = yourJsVariables to SASS
   2. compile (variablesDef + originalFile)

Perhaps it's not the ideal solution for you but I think the key is to define variables in JS not trying to access them from your css format.